# Parsing a stringified JSON coming from a Google Sheet Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm trying to parse a stringified JSON output from a web app created from a google sheets script. I thought it couldn't be that complicated, but I've tried everything I could think of or find out online... so now asking for help if that's OK!

on the web app / Google Sheets side, the code is:

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetID');
  var worksheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Rankings C/U');
  var output = JSON.stringify({ data: worksheet.getDataRange().getValues() });
  
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);
}
```

I've published the script, the web app works, I'm OK with that bit.

I've put random values on the spreadsheet: [[1,2],[3,4]] if we speak in matrix format.

on the other end, I've tried a bunch of stuff including .fetch, JSON.parse() to get the data in a usable format within the Google Sites embedded code, but the real issue is that I think I can't get to allocate the payload to a variable?

I'm using Google Sites to fetch the data.
with the basic module "<> embed", with the "by URL" option, with the following code:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec
```

I get the following output - that looks what it should be:

```
{"data":[[1,2],[3,4]]}
```

but when trying to include this in a script module ("embed code") - no chance!

```
<form name="get-images">
  <input name="test" id="test" value="we'll put the contents of cell A1 here">
</form>

<script>
   const form = document.forms['get-images']
   var usableVariable = JSON.parse("https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec"); // here I'm trying to allocate the stringified JSON to a variable
   form.elements['test'].value = usableVariable[1,1]; //allocating the first element of the parsed array  
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious - but now I ran out of ideas!

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: In your case, I think that `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);` is required to be modified to `return ContentService.createTextOutput(output);`. But from `var test = https://script.google.com/macros/s/scriptID/exec;` and `form.elements['test'].value = 123;`, I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike for reverting back so quickly! let me edit the post to clarify

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't to have changed the outcome. Even if the "by URL" embedded code provides an output, I still can't get to allocate the string to a variable in a script.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw your updated question. What is the script of `but when trying to include this in a script` and `I've tried JSON.parse() and UrlFetchApp.fetch()`? You are trying to use Google Apps Script in HTML and Javascript? And I cannot understand about `if this line doesn't process in the preview window of the embedded code insert, I understand that the previous line (the allocation) is illegal and stops the code execution`. So I cannot still understand what you want to do. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike, I'm merely trying to use data stored in a Google sheet in this Google site.

Comment: I've deleted the last bit of code that was confusing - we actually don't need to care about how I check whether it works or not. It just doesn't :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. What is the updated script?

Comment: I've just cut the end, which was confusing. Basically, the UrlFetchApp.fetch() function doesn't work. JSON.parse() doesn't work either. Would you have examples of what could work?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. When I could correctly understand about your question. I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your question soon.

Comment: no problem that's fine, thanks for considering it already! and don't worry about your English that's all good! let me know if you need any additional clarification.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I can understand about the top script in your question is Google Apps Script. But I cannot understand about the bottom script in your question. So I cannot still think of the solution. I apologize for this.

Comment: OK then, I've made the question clearer: how to display the content of cell A1 of the spreadsheet in the input text field of the HTML form?
and I have amended the script code to reflect this goal.
hope that makes more sense now :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your bottom script is HTML file. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, where is the HTML file? For example, it's in your local PC or in Google Apps Script project?

Comment: there is no HTML file, the HTML + Java script is within an "embed code" module hosted on a Google Sites, as explained [here](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/90569?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, the bottom script is embedded to the Google site, you want to retrieve the values from `doGet` and want to put the value of cell "B2" to the input tag. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the settings of Web Apps? Those are `Execute the app as:` and `Who has access to the app:`.

Comment: Your understanding is correct :) (cell A1, or B2, any cell really)
The parameters are: 
Execute the app as: Me, 
Who has access to the app: Anyone, even Anonymous

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In your situation, the bottom script is embedded to the Google site.
- You want to retrieve the values from `doGet` and want to put the value of cell "B2" to the input tag.
- The settings of Web Apps is `Execute the app as: Me` and `Who has access to the app: Anyone, even Anonymous`.

### Modification points:

- In your case, I think that `return ContentService.createTextOutput(output);` is suitable instead of `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(output);` in Google Apps Script.
- In order to retrieve the values from `doGet`, in this modification, `fetch` is used.
- You want to retrieve the cell "B2" from `usableVariable[1,1];`, please modify it to `usableVariable[1][1];`

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetID');
  var worksheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Rankings C/U');
  var output = JSON.stringify({ data: worksheet.getDataRange().getValues() });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output);
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

```
<form name="get-images">
  <input name="test" id="test" value="we'll put the contents of cell A1 here">
</form>

<script>
  let url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => {
      const usableVariable = res.data;
      const form = document.forms['get-images'];
      form.elements['test'].value = usableVariable[1][1];  // usableVariable[1][1] is the cell "B2".
    });
</script>
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- In my environment, I could confirm that above HTML & Javascript worked in the Google site by embedding.

### References:

- [Class ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)
- [Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: thank you so much, it works!!!! the coding around ``` fetch() ``` wasn't obvious to me and I was miles away from figuring it out. Hopefully this use case serves others too. Thanks again for your patience!!

Comment: @FanF Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand and think of the solution by your cooperating. Thank you, too.